# Is there any good video analysys(detecting people on the video) library for Java(Android) OR C#(Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, java, android, windows-phone

I am going to create program which will detect **moving** objects(in that case people) on the video. I have to select the platform Android or Windows Phone I do not know on which platform it will be easier to code it.

By easy I mean that there is running free library which gives me simple tools to analyse video. I have much more expierience with Windows Phone but I know Java well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaCV library can do that it Java interface to OpenCV it can detect faces and do different processing to images and videos

Comment: Will I be able to detect head(not face) if somebody is turned back? If not will I have access to plain pixels(rgb) as an array or any other collection?

Answer (score 0):

you could try EMGU CV, a free C# wrapper of the OpenCV library. I used it a couple of years ago for some movement detection methods using web cams, so it should be able to do what you need.

link: www.emgu.com